# How can I consume all messages from the queue and stop the callback function in pika?

Tags: python-3.x, pika

I need you to run the callback function and get all messages in the queue up to that moment and then close the callback

```
    for method, properties, body in rabbitCanal.consume(fila):

        try:
            mensagem = json.loads(body)
            a = parse.parser(mensagem)
            if a:
                self.lista.append(a)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.